# Display clock frequency per core using Conky

Tags: cpu, conky, multi-core, cpufreq, frequency

I am using Conky to display a lot of information of my system. I managed to display the load percentage per core. But I do not know how to display the clock frequency of each core. What I have now is:

```
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}PROCESSORS ${hr 2}${font}
CPU1: ${cpu cpu1}% $alignr ${freq} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu1 8,60}
CPU2: ${cpu cpu2}% $alignr ${freq} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu2 8,60}
CPU3: ${cpu cpu3}% $alignr ${freq} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu3 8,60}
CPU4: ${cpu cpu4}% $alignr ${freq} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu4 8,60}
CPU5: ${cpu cpu5}% $alignr ${freq} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu5 8,60}
CPU6: ${cpu cpu6}% $alignr ${freq} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu6 8,60}
CPU7: ${cpu cpu7}% $alignr ${freq} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu7 8,60}
CPU8: ${cpu cpu8}% $alignr ${freq} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu8 8,60}
```

But this only gives me the global clock frequency and not the individual clock frequency per core. Does someone know how to get the individual clock frequency per core?

**System information**

- Linux Mint 13 KDE, 64 bit (based on Ubuntu 12.04)
- Intel i7-2670QM (quad core with multithreading)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `conky` you can execute an external command. So `/proc/cpuinfo` has all the info you need. see:

```
root@host:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz"
cpu MHz         : 2667.000
cpu MHz         : 1998.000
cpu MHz         : 1998.000
cpu MHz         : 2667.000
```

In my case there are 4 cores and two of them are one [step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepping_level) down. You can find out which steps your CPU allows with a tool called `cpufreq-info`:

```
root@host:~$ cpufreq-info | grep "available frequency steps"
  available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.00 GHz
```

This package can be installed by the command:

```
apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

With this information I would write your `conky.conf` like this

```
${font sans-serif:bold:size=8}PROCESSORS ${hr 2}${font}
CPU1: ${cpu cpu1}% $alignr ${exec awk '/cpu MHz/{i++}i==1{printf "%.f",$4; exit}' /proc/cpuinfo} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu1 8,60}
CPU2: ${cpu cpu2}% $alignr ${exec awk '/cpu MHz/{i++}i==2{printf "%.f",$4; exit}' /proc/cpuinfo} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu2 8,60}
CPU3: ${cpu cpu3}% $alignr ${exec awk '/cpu MHz/{i++}i==3{printf "%.f",$4; exit}' /proc/cpuinfo} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu3 8,60}
CPU4: ${cpu cpu4}% $alignr ${exec awk '/cpu MHz/{i++}i==4{printf "%.f",$4; exit}' /proc/cpuinfo} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu4 8,60}
CPU5: ${cpu cpu5}% $alignr ${exec awk '/cpu MHz/{i++}i==5{printf "%.f",$4; exit}' /proc/cpuinfo} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu5 8,60}
CPU6: ${cpu cpu6}% $alignr ${exec awk '/cpu MHz/{i++}i==6{printf "%.f",$4; exit}' /proc/cpuinfo} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu6 8,60}
CPU7: ${cpu cpu7}% $alignr ${exec awk '/cpu MHz/{i++}i==7{printf "%.f",$4; exit}' /proc/cpuinfo} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu7 8,60}
CPU8: ${cpu cpu8}% $alignr ${exec awk '/cpu MHz/{i++}i==8{printf "%.f",$4; exit}' /proc/cpuinfo} MHz $alignr ${cpubar cpu8 8,60}
```

In my case it worked, but i had only 4 cores.

Comment: It is because of [Simultaneous Multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading). I wonder if there's a way to use it per core and not per thread.