# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS performs bad

Tags: laptop, performance, toshiba-satellite

I got a Thoshiba Satellite L745: i3 2310M, 8 GB RAM, 160 GB Intel SSD.

The Ubuntu UI is not very responsive when navigating throught menus and files.

What should I do to get better performance?

Comment: Install Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity instead of Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome. It will be much faster. 18.04 is brand new and it will take them awhile to fine-tune it. Ubuntu 16.04 came out two years ago and has another three year lifespan.

Comment: I was thinking about trying Ubuntu Mate or Budgie, would you recommend that?

Comment: I tried Lubuntu 16.04 in a virtual machine because it was supposed to be "lighter". I didn't like the fact the familiar `nautilus` (file manager) and `gedit` (text editor) were gone. They were replaced with foreign `pacman` and `leafpad` which I had to learn. Also the new apps aren't as widely discussed with tips, tricks and solutions here in Ask Ubuntu. You would find the same thing with **Budgie** and **Mate**. Of course you would go to their websites and not **Ask Ubuntu** website though. I can only recommend you do as much research as time permits and follow your instincts.

Comment: Try this first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/604720/setting-to-high-performance?noredirect=1#comment1735291_1047763 Last user says it "works like a charm" for speeding up his i5 processors.

Comment: If you are coming from Windows (especially older Windows) the Lubuntu interface may seem more familiar.  YMMV.  Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix for the reference to your other answer, I am trying that on an underperforming netbook.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Don't get me wrong the Lubuntu apps weren't that big of a stumbling block for me, more of an annoyance at the differences. As for part 2: I was pleasantly surprised another user said it helped with performance--I thought it automatic dynamic CPU frequency adjustments was the way to go. On a netbook I wonder if overheating would be a concern?

Comment: How do you enable that hardware monitor? Can not comment in the other post

Comment: Try MATE. I prefer it to the standard Ubuntu. The UI is simple and you will find much better performance. Before investing a lot of time into a new Ubuntu installation, give MATE a try.