# Conky not displaying Nvidia GPU data

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu, conky

I'm using the below conky script but it's not showing the Nvidia GPU details as shown in the below screenshot:

```
override_utf8_locale yes
use_xft yes
xftfont ubuntu:size=10.5
xftalpha 0.5
uppercase no
no_buffers yes              # Subtract cached and buffered ram from memory usage.
short_units yes             # Use "G" instead of "GiB"

text_buffer_size 2048
update_interval 2.5          # change to .001 for 1000 times per second stress test
own_window_class Conky
own_window yes
own_window_type dock
own_window_transparent no
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 145  # semi-transparent
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
minimum_size 400
maximum_width 400
alignment top_right

draw_shades yes
# off-white
default_color ECEAE4
# blue
color1 1EB5FF
# light blue
color2 30DDFB
# dark blue
color3 0090ff
# lime
color4 98FF76
default_shade_color 000000

draw_outline no
draw_borders no
stippled_borders 0

TEXT
#------------+
# Distro     |
#------------+
${color}Today is:${color green}$alignr${time %A,}$alignr ${time %e %B %G}
${color}Distribution:${color green}$alignr ${execi 6300 cat /etc/issue.net} $machine
${color}Kernel:$alignr${color green} $kernel
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
#------------+
# i7-6700 CPU|
#------------+
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® i-7 6700HQ 3.5 GHz: ${color1}@  ${color green}${freq} MHz
${color}${goto 13}CPU 0 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu1}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu1 18}
#${cpugauge cpu1 20,40}
#${cpugraph 1 15,200 555555 AAAAAA -l}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 1 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu2}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu2 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 2 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu3}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu3 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 3 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu4}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu4 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 4 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu5}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu5 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 5 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu6}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu6 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 6 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu7}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu7 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 7 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu8}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu8 18}
#------------+
# Temperature|
#------------+
#${color1}All CPUs ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone7/temp | cut -c1-2}°C ${alignr}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
# Next line is for kernel >= 4.13.0-36-generic
${color1}All CPUs ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 1 temp 1}°C ${alignr}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
# Next line is for temperature with Kerenel 4.4
#${color1}All CPUs ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 0 temp 1}°C ${alignr}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
${color green}$running_processes ${color1}running of ${color green}$processes ${color1}loaded processes.
${color1}Load Average 1-5-15 minutes: ${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $1}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $2}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $3}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4}
#------------+
# Intel iGPU |
#------------+
${color orange}${hr 1}${if_match "intel" == "${execpi 99999 prime-select query}"}
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® Skylake GT2 HD 530 iGPU @${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_cur_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color}${goto 13}Min. Freq:${goto 120}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_min_freq_mhz)} MHz${color}${goto 210}Max. Freq:${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_max_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color orange}${hr 1}${else}
#------------+
# Nvidia GPU |
#------------+
${color2}${voffset 5}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}@ ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.sm --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader)}°C
${color1}${voffset 5}Ver: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1} P-State: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=pstate --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}BIOS: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=vbios_version --format=csv,noheader)}
${color1}${voffset 5}GPU:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Ram:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Pwr:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Freq: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.mem --format=csv,noheader)}
${color orange}${hr 1}${endif}
#------------+
# Prcoesses  |
#------------+
${color1}${voffset 5}Process Name: ${goto 200}PID ${goto 265}CPU% ${alignr}Mem%
${color}${goto 13}${top name 1} ${goto 190}${top pid 1} ${goto 270}${color green}${top cpu 1} ${alignr}${top mem 1}
${color}${goto 13}${top name 2} ${goto 190}${top pid 2} ${goto 270}${color green}${top cpu 2} ${alignr}${top mem 2}
${color}${goto 13}${top name 3} ${goto 190}${top pid 3} ${goto 270}${color green}${top cpu 3} ${alignr}${top mem 3}
${color}${goto 13}${top name 4} ${goto 190}${top pid 4} ${goto 270}${color green}${top cpu 4} ${alignr}${top mem 4}
${color}${goto 13}${top name 5} ${goto 190}${top pid 5} ${goto 270}${color green}${top cpu 5} ${alignr}${top mem 5}
${color}${goto 13}${top name 6} ${goto 190}${top pid 6} ${goto 270}${color green}${top cpu 6} ${alignr}${top mem 6}
${color}${goto 13}${top name 7} ${goto 190}${top pid 7} ${goto 270}${color green}${top cpu 7} ${alignr}${top mem 7}
${color}${goto 13}${top name 8} ${goto 190}${top pid 8} ${goto 270}${color green}${top cpu 8} ${alignr}${top mem 8}
${color}${goto 13}${top name 9} ${goto 190}${top pid 9} ${goto 270}${color green}${top cpu 9} ${alignr}${top mem 9}
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
#------------+
# Storage    |
#------------+
${color1}RAM Use/Free:${goto 148}${color red}$mem ${color red} ${goto 220}${membar 15,100} $alignr${color}${memeasyfree}
${color1}Linux Root:${goto 148}${color red}${fs_used /} ${color red} ${goto 220}${fs_bar 15,100 /} $alignr${color}${fs_free /}
${color1}Ubuntu 18.04:${goto 148}${if_mounted /mnt/clone}${color red} ${fs_used /mnt/clone} ${color red} ${goto 220}${fs_bar 15,100 /mnt/clone} $alignr${color}${fs_free /mnt/clone}${else} ${color yellow} /mnt/clone ${endif}
${color1}${if_mounted /mnt/old}Broken 16.04:${goto 148}${color red} ${fs_used /mnt/old} ${color red} ${goto 220}${fs_bar 15,100 /mnt/old} $alignr${color}${fs_free /mnt/old}${else}Cache RAM:${goto 148}${color green}${cached} ${color1} ${alignr}Buffers: ${color green} ${buffers}${endif}
${color1}${if_mounted /mnt/e}WSL+Linux:${goto 148}${color red}${fs_used /mnt/e} ${color red} ${goto 220}${fs_bar 15,100 /mnt/e} $alignr${color}${fs_free /mnt/e}${else}Swap:${goto 148}${color green}${swap} / ${swapmax} $alignr${color green}${swapperc}%${endif}
#${color}NVMe Win 10:${goto 148}${if_mounted /mnt/c}${color green} ${fs_used /mnt/c} / ${fs_size /mnt/c} $alignr${color green}${fs_used_perc /mnt/c}%${else}${color yellow}/mnt/c${endif}
#${color}${if_mounted /mnt/d}HGST_Win10:${goto 148}${color red} ${fs_used /mnt/d} / ${fs_size /mnt/d} $alignr${color green}${fs_used_perc /mnt/d}%${else}Cache RAM:${goto 148}${color green}${cached} ${color} Buffers: ${color green} ${buffers}${endif}
#${color}${if_mounted /mnt/e}WSL+Linux:${goto 148}${color red}${fs_used /mnt/e} / ${fs_size /mnt/e} $alignr${color red}${fs_used_perc /mnt/e}%${else}Swap:${goto 148}${color green}${swap} / ${swapmax} $alignr${color green}${swapperc}%${endif}
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
#------------+
# Network    |
#------------+
#${color1}Network using vnStat "-i", "-w" and "-m"
${color}${goto 5}Today ${goto 100}Yesterday ${goto 225}Week ${goto 325}Month ${color green}
# vnstatd updates database every five minutes
${execi 300 vnstat -i enp59s0 | grep "today" | awk '{print $8" "substr ($9, 1, 1)}'} ${goto 110}${execi 300 vnstat -i enp59s0 | grep "yesterday" | awk '{print $8" "substr ($9, 1, 1)}'} ${goto 220}${execi 300 vnstat -i enp59s0 -w | grep "current week" | awk '{print $9" "substr ($10, 1, 1)}'} ${goto 315}${execi 300 vnstat -i enp59s0 -m | grep "`date +"%b '%y"`" | awk '{print $9" "substr ($10, 1, 1)}'}
${color}Down: ${color green}${downspeed enp59s0}/s ${color}${goto 220}Up: ${color green}${upspeed enp59s0}/s
${downspeedgraph enp59s0 25,190 000000 ff0000} ${alignr}${upspeedgraph enp59s0 25,190 000000 00ff00}$color
Total: ${color green}${totaldown enp59s0} $color${alignr}Total: ${color green}${totalup enp59s0}
#Bit Rate:$color ${wireless_bitrate wlp60s0}
#------------+
# Brightness |
#------------+
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
${color1}${goto 5}Rise: ${color green}${execpi 300 cat /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunrise} ${goto 155}${color1}Set: ${color green}${execpi 300 cat /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunset} ${alignr}${color1}Level: ${color green}${execpi 10 cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness}
```

[image]

And this is the output when I run `nvidia-smi`:

[image]

And if I run the commands separately in terminal they retrieve the right information as shown below, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

[image]

This is the terminal output when running `conky` in terminal:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here is a minimal version of my file and the resulted output:

```
override_utf8_locale yes
use_xft yes
xftfont ubuntu:size=10.5
xftalpha 0.5
uppercase no
no_buffers yes              # Subtract cached and buffered ram from memory usage.
short_units yes             # Use "G" instead of "GiB"

text_buffer_size 2048
update_interval 2.5          # change to .001 for 1000 times per second stress test
own_window_class Conky
own_window yes
own_window_type dock
own_window_transparent no
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 145  # semi-transparent
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
minimum_size 400
maximum_width 400
alignment top_right

draw_shades yes
# off-white
default_color ECEAE4
# blue
color1 1EB5FF
# light blue
color2 30DDFB
# dark blue
color3 0090ff
# lime
color4 98FF76
default_shade_color 000000

draw_outline no
draw_borders no
stippled_borders 0
TEXT

#------------+
# Nvidia GPU |
#------------+
${color2}${voffset 5}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}@ ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.sm --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader)}°C
${color1}${voffset 5}Ver: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1} P-State: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=pstate --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}BIOS: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=vbios_version --format=csv,noheader)}
${color1}${voffset 5}GPU:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Ram:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Pwr:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Freq: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.mem --format=csv,noheader)}
${color orange}${hr 1}
```

This produces:

[image: conky screenshot]

Comment: Run conky from the terminal. Do you see any errors?

Comment: @terdon I've updated the question with the terminal output of running `conky`

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](//askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: The next step is to remove _everything_ not related. Make your conkyrc as simple as possible so we can focus on the problem without being distracted by the other stuff there. A minimal version of your file (without the ifdef) works fine on my system. So try and see if a minimal one (with only the NVDIA section) works for you too.

Comment: If making a new file for testing it would be beneficial to make sure a single `execpi` works such as `date` to return the current time.

Comment: @terdon I've updated my question with a minimal version of the file.

Comment: Hmm. I can run that file with no issues on my system. Still, that's far from minimal. Try removing _everything_ except a single command. For example, keep `${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader)}` and nothing else. Does that still fail?

Comment: Also, why in the world are you running all of these commands every 0.001 second? That will bring your machine to its knees! You shouldn't use `execpi` if the information doesn't change (so not fot the GPU name or BIOS version) and for the rest, just update every second or two, not every 100th of a second!

Comment: @terdon that was the problem, when I changed the time delay to 1 sec it worked! Could you write a solution and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious issue I see in your file is that you are running these commands every 1/1000th of a second! That's an absurdly intense load and will likely bring your machine to its knees. It's also pointless since in most cases there is no reason for that level of detail and in others you're using it for commands whose output never changes (like the name of your card or its BIOS version).

So, first only use `execpi` when the output of the command you are running changes regularly. Second, use a sane interval (e.g. 1 or 10) instead of 0.001.

Comment: The conky update interval is set to 2.5 seconds. I will check when I get home but I was under the impression execpi interval can only override to slower interval not a faster interval than the conky global interval.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yeah, [that's what the docs say](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html). But the OP said this worked. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for your GPU but I notice your temperature is blank. The code is:

```
#${color1}All CPUs ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone7/temp | cut -c1-2}°C ${alignr}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
# Next line is for kernel >= 4.13.0-36-generic
${color1}All CPUs ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 1 temp 1}°C ${alignr}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
# Next line is for temperature with Kerenel 4.4
#${color1}All CPUs ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 0 temp 1}°C ${alignr}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
```

Remove the comment (`#`) from the first line and place a comment in front of the third line. Then save the file twice in a row. This will reload the conky configuration without having to manually kill it and restart it.

If that doesn't work then place a comment on the first line and remove the comment from the fifth line. Then save the file twice.

---

I also noticed your system isn't displaying the Ubuntu font but rather a version of the courier font. It seems this line isn't working or you do not have the font installed:

```
xftfont ubuntu:size=10.5
```

I wonder if this might be due to locale or language settings.

Comment: I tried commenting the third line and uncommenting the first line but still the temperature not showing up.

Comment: What about uncommenting the fifth line and commenting the others?

Comment: Still not showing up