# Ubuntu 20.04 becomes super slow

Tags: 20.04, dell

My Ubuntu becomes extremely slow suddenly.
When I reboot it works for a while and then it becomes super slow again.

I have a Dell lattitude 7400 connected to a DisplayLink D6000

It happens mostly when the Dock is plugged but not only.

For example, during the indexing of files in PHPStorm, my computer is unusable.
Here is the `htop` during ex
**htop**
[image: htop]

Here are some logs I could find when it starts to be slow :

**/var/log/syslog**

```
Jun  7 11:49:59 bastio-Latitude-7400 wpa_supplicant[948]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-44 noise=9999 txrate=866700
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 25405
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.00  1920 1936 1952 2104  1080 1083 1097 1116 +hsync -vsync (67.0 kHz eP)
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  112.80  1920 1936 1952 2104  1080 1083 1097 1116 +hsync -vsync (53.6 kHz e)
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 25405
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.00  1920 1936 1952 2104  1080 1083 1097 1116 +hsync -vsync (67.0 kHz eP)
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  112.80  1920 1936 1952 2104  1080 1083 1097 1116 +hsync -vsync (53.6 kHz e)
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.502949] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503007] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503048] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:90 (dev=1) poll connector state: connected
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503055] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_get_edid_copy:242 (dev=1) EDID valid
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503721] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:90 (dev=0) poll connector state: connected
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503727] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_get_edid_copy:242 (dev=0) EDID valid
Jun  7 11:51:43 bastio-Latitude-7400 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Jun  7 11:51:44 bastio-Latitude-7400 systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
Jun  7 11:51:44 bastio-Latitude-7400 systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jun  7 11:51:55 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Jun  7 11:53:42 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: message repeated 9 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.]
Jun  7 11:53:42 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Successfully made thread 5669 of process 5541 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Jun  7 11:53:42 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jun  7 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: message repeated 10 times: [ Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.]
Jun  7 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Successfully made thread 5856 of process 5718 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Jun  7 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 9 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
```

**journalctl -f**

```
juin 07 11:48:01 bastio-Latitude-7400 gnome-shell[2748]: Window manager warning: WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x2000670 for 0x20006a6 window override-redirect is an override-redirect window and this is not correct according to the standard, so we'll fallback to the first non-override-redirect window 0x200004c.
juin 07 11:48:23 bastio-Latitude-7400 gnome-shell[2748]: Could not create selection source for X11: Le format TARGETS n'est pas pris en charge
juin 07 11:49:11 bastio-Latitude-7400 wpa_supplicant[948]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-49 noise=9999 txrate=866700
juin 07 11:49:12 bastio-Latitude-7400 gnome-shell[2748]: Could not create selection source for X11: Le format TARGETS n'est pas pris en charge
juin 07 11:49:45 bastio-Latitude-7400 gnome-shell[2748]: Could not create selection source for X11: Le format TARGETS n'est pas pris en charge
juin 07 11:49:53 bastio-Latitude-7400 gnome-shell[2748]: Window manager warning: WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x2000c94 for 0x2000ca7 window override-redirect is an override-redirect window and this is not correct according to the standard, so we'll fallback to the first non-override-redirect window 0x200004c.
juin 07 11:49:59 bastio-Latitude-7400 wpa_supplicant[948]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-44 noise=9999 txrate=866700
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 25405
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.00  1920 1936 1952 2104  1080 1083 1097 1116 +hsync -vsync (67.0 kHz eP)
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  112.80  1920 1936 1952 2104  1080 1083 1097 1116 +hsync -vsync (53.6 kHz e)
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 25405
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.00  1920 1936 1952 2104  1080 1083 1097 1116 +hsync -vsync (67.0 kHz eP)
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2313]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  112.80  1920 1936 1952 2104  1080 1083 1097 1116 +hsync -vsync (53.6 kHz e)
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_detect:90 (dev=1) poll connector state: connected
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_painter_get_edid_copy:242 (dev=1) EDID valid
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_detect:90 (dev=0) poll connector state: connected
juin 07 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: evdi: [D] evdi_painter_get_edid_copy:242 (dev=0) EDID valid
juin 07 11:51:43 bastio-Latitude-7400 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
juin 07 11:51:44 bastio-Latitude-7400 systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
juin 07 11:51:44 bastio-Latitude-7400 systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
juin 07 11:51:55 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:51:55 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:52:59 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:52:59 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:53:04 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:53:04 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:53:42 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:53:42 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:53:42 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:53:42 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:53:42 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Successfully made thread 5669 of process 5541 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
juin 07 11:53:42 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:55:26 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:55:26 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Successfully made thread 5856 of process 5718 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
juin 07 11:57:27 bastio-Latitude-7400 rtkit-daemon[1162]: Supervising 9 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
```

**/var/log/kern.log**

```
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.502949] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503007] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503048] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:90 (dev=1) poll connector state: connected
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503055] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_get_edid_copy:242 (dev=1) EDID valid
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503721] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:90 (dev=0) poll connector state: connected
Jun  7 11:51:02 bastio-Latitude-7400 kernel: [  864.503727] evdi: [D] evdi_painter_get_edid_copy:242 (dev=0) EDID valid
```

**UPDATE:**
I am on a dualBoot, when i use the computer on windows I don't get any error.

Comment: how much RAM does your system have?

Comment: Has you can see in the htop, I have lot of free RAM space with 15.5G in total

Answer (score 2):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: Does the screenshot of "htop" helps you ? 
It seems I have lot of free RAM but CPU goes  crazy

Answer (score 0):

You can try to switch your laptop to performance mode it is explained how to do this in this thread:

[Setting to High Performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604720/setting-to-high-performance)

for me it only work for some time after booting my system. My laptop even when every core is using 100% is very quiet and this is strange for me. Did you maybe solved your problem somehow different?