# After upgrading from ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 22.04.1, power mode is not available

Tags: upgrade, power-management, 22.04

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 20.04 installation to Ubuntu 22.04.1. Everything appeared normal after rebooting, but I didn't get the power and performance management mode. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how it is handled at [How does Ubuntu 22.04 handle power modes?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1406165).

Check if the power profiling daemon is installed or active.

To install,

```
sudo apt-get install power-profiles-daemon
```

And voila!
You can see the power mode in the settings and the gnome menu.
If not, try restarting your system.