# Is there any downside to running Ubuntu 22.04 in "Performance Mode" all the time?

Tags: power-management, battery

Ubuntu 22.04 introduces a handy way to set the power mode: Performance, Balanced, Battery Saver. Some info here: [How does Ubuntu 22.04 handle power modes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406165/how-does-ubuntu-22-04-handle-power-modes)

While I get that it makes tweaks to, say, save the battery, my questions are:

- Is there any "downside" to keeping it in performance mode all the time while plugged in?
- Is this taxing my system?
- Will my computer (chips, battery, etc) last longer keeping it in "Balanced" mode as much as possible when plugged in?

Further notes: I definitely notice my fan kicks on more frequently, making me think things are getting hotter. But apps are definitely snappier, especially graphics and data heavy programs. Occasionally the battery charge dips, leading me to think that it's using so much energy my charger can't keep up.

Comment: From experience … CPU heating will most likely not cause any permanent damage to system components but, high performance dedicated GPU overheating might cause serious damage especially in laptops and mini PCs … If your fans are working and the platform of your laptop is modern, I’d probably be less concerned regarding using high performance mode all the time … That is however just my opinion based on my experience and not solid science :-)