# High ram consumption on steam games

Tags: 22.04, games, steam, ram

If I check the ram consumption of the system is not the same as the use of the game and processes that I'm running, the higher consumption leads to a crash of my system because of full memory and I have 8GB.

I checked on the internet that people that are playing the same games in windows have even half ram usage, why?

This is an example with "yooka laylee and the impossible lair" but this happens with all games:

[System monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9qhp.png)

[Processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syko2.png)

The game running on a windows machine with the OS using 3gb ram total:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEiHhL2pXm4

Comment: The "same" software - not really the same in any scenartio - running in different OSes often have different resources usage. No pint in comparing it.

Comment: I see in your screenshots that the memory usage of the game process is about the same as windows but the overall system memory is not even if you sum up all the processes, something is taking up ram when you run the game maybe cache?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few we have no influence on: Windows is not Linux. Sub-optimal 3rd party drivers. Open GL. The games you picked are made with Windows in mind and Linux as an afterthought.

Then it is possible your graphics card driver is not set to performance mode. That one you can alter: [Setting to High Performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604720/setting-to-high-performance)

> I checked on the internet that people that are playing the same games in windows have even half ram usage, why?

That is a severely flawed comparison. Do they have the exact same setup? And do you also have their statistics when using Linux? If not how do you know their systems are not also using more memory using Linux?

If you want an optimal gaming performance use a gaming oriented platform. Gaming on Linux is still a niche despite the good work the people of Steam do. It will always be an uphill battle against Microsoft, hardware manufacturers, and content creators.